# How to get the id or the row in parent grid when there is a link in the row of the subgrid in jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I have a `Grid` and a `SubGrid`. When the user clicks on the row in `Grid` to expand the `SubGrid`, I have a link in one of the columns of the `SubGrid`. In the url of this link in the SubGrid, I want access to the ID of the row from the parent id. Is this doable?

Below is how I'm creating a link at each row of the sub grid. This was taken by an answer from [Oleg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/315935/oleg)

```
loadComplete: function() {
    var ids = jQuery('#'+subgridTableId).getDataIDs();
    var myGridNode = jQuery('#'+subgridTableId)[0];
        for (var i = 0, idCount = ids.length; i < idCount; i++) {
               var a = $("#"+ids[i]+" a",myGridNode);
               a.html("Link Name");
               a.click(function(e) {
                     var hash=e.currentTarget.hash;
                     if (hash.substring(0,5) === '#?id=') {//do something }
               }
        }
    }
```

So, my question is whether there is a way in jqGrid to access the id of the parent row in the subgrid inside the `loadComplete` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
loadComplete: function() {
  var ids = jQuery('#'+subgridTableId).getDataIDs();
  var myGridNode = jQuery('#'+subgridTableId)[0];
  for (var i = 0, idCount = ids.length; i < idCount; i++) {
    var a = $("#"+ids[i]+" a",myGridNode);
    a.html("Link Name");
    $(a).live('click',function()
    {
      var hash=e.currentTarget.hash;
      thisParentRowID = $(this).parent().attr('id');
      if (hash.substring(0,5) === thisParentRowID) {
        //do something
      }
    });
  }
}
```